# SSL error - Certificates Verify Failed when accessing website with Requests

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to connect with website to run webscrapping, but I'm stuck at SSL Error.

```
import urllib,ssl
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import certifi
import ssl

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/synergia/loguj"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

gives error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    977         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 978             conn.connect()
    979 

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    361 
--> 362         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    363             sock=conn,

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data)
    385         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 386             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    387 

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    499         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501             sock=sock,

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040                     self.do_handshake()
   1041             except (OSError, ValueError):

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1308                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310         finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    725 
--> 726             retries = retries.increment(
    727                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    445         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 446             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    447 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.librus.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rodzina/synergia/loguj (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-04d12114a1d8> in <module>
     12 with requests.Session() as s:
     13     url = "https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/synergia/loguj"
---> 14     r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
     15     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
     16     login_data["form_build_id"] = soup.find("input", attrs={"name": "form_build_id"})[

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    541 
    542         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 543         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    544 
    545     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

c:\Apps\Anaconda3\v3_8_5_x64\Local\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.librus.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rodzina/synergia/loguj (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Sorry for putting so long error massage but maybe there are some useful details.
Website is running fine in the browser but python can't cover the certificates. Can you advise how to deal with this?
Thanks,
Paulina

Comment: Which Python version? Please always post whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: I can only guess that for some reason you don't have the DigiCert Global Root CA installed. Try `pip3 install -U certifi` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i had already installed cerfiti, now i updated and still got the same error.

Comment: Do you have multiple Python interpreters? Are you sure you updated the correct one?

Comment: Can you just set Verify=False? r = s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)